# Solr:Exception writing document id xxx to the index

Tags: solr

possible analysis error:
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB7TV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVuZD.png)

But I check linux memory by using the command of 'df -h' and 'df -i'.It have free space.And the Solr JVM Memory have free space too. How should I solve this problem? Please help me.

Comment: Please include all relevant details _as text_ in your question instead of as images - images aren't searchable, doesn't have proper accessibility, isn't copy and paste-friendly and requires the reader to jump between pages or views.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have enough free space when *merging the index files*. Your stack trace shows that this is happening when Lucene attempts to merge the index files into a single file. The regular case will require at least enough free space on the disk to duplicate the index, but you should try to have at least 2x the index size available as free space (so in total, disk space available to solr should be 3x the expected index size).

Merging the index files requires taking the existing index, then merging the content into a new index file, and then removing the old files - so after the merge has completed, Lucene have used 2x the disk space of the index (since it effectively has two indexes present) before removal of the previous index can start.